# Values of properties is returned empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to read the values in the property file. Why I get values: [] in the output?

```
abc.env[0].envname=test
abc.env[0].grant_type=password

abc.env[1].envname=dev
abc.env[1].grant_type=password
```

Below is the class I'm trying to execute

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AbcApplication implements CommandLineRunner{

    private static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbcApplication.class);

    @Autowired
    ReadAbcApplicationProperties readAbcApplicationProperties;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AbcApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        LOG.info("values: {}", readAbcApplicationProperties.getAbcSources());
    }

}
```

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public class ReadAbcApplicationProperties {

    private List<AbcProperties> abcSources = new ArrayList<AbcProperties>();

    @Autowired
    ReadAbcApplicationProperties readAbcApplicationProperties;

    public List<AbcProperties> getAbcSources() {
        return abcSources;
    }

    public void setAbcSources(List<AbcProperties> abcSources) {
        this.abcSources = abcSources;
    }
    
}
```

```
public class AbcProperties {

    private String envname;
    private String tokenGrantType;

    public String getEnvname() {
        return envname;
    }
    public void setEnvname(String envname) {
        this.envname = envname;
    }
    public String getTokenGrantType() {
        return tokenGrantType;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with the missing part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some inconsistencies in your code..

- `ReadAbcApplicationProperties` - Why you inject itself in ?

  ```
   @Autowired
   ReadAbcApplicationProperties readAbcApplicationProperties;
  ```

  This line must be removed.
- field `private String tokenGrantType` is not consistent with `abc.env[0].grant_type` in properties file
- `private List<AbcProperties> abcSources` is not consistent with `abc.env[0]` and `abc.env[1]` and ... `abc.env[X]` in properties file

The classes should be:

**AbcProperties**

```
public class AbcProperties {

  private String envname;
  private String grantType; //to match `grant_type` in .properties file
  
  //getters setters
}
```

**ReadAbcApplicationProperties**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "abc")
public class ReadAbcApplicationProperties {

    private List<AbcProperties> env = new ArrayList<>(); //to match abc.env[X] in properties file

    // getters setters
}
```

I tried the above in a spring-boot sample project and it works
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and time! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

You have different property names in property file and corresponding bean class `AbcProperties`. see `tokenGrantType` and `grant_type`.

An ideal configuration would be:

Apologies for using yml file instead of properties, but it all behaves the same. It's just `yml` would gives us more readability.

```yaml
myapp: # this can be your prefix
  abc:
    - 
      envname: test
      grant_type: password
    - 
      envname: dev
      grant_type: password
```

> Having "myapp" as prefix(top-level key), woudl enable you to add any number of properties inside a single class like below 'ConfigPropertiesBinder'.

```
@Data // If not, include getter and setters, with cons.
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myapp")
public class ConfigPropertiesBinder {

    private List<AbcProperties> abc; // Should match with myapp.abc

  // Other properties
    
}
```

```
  @Data
  public class AbcProperties{
   private String envname; // Match with myapp.abc[x].envname
   private String grantType; // '-' and '_' converts to camelcase
  }
```

See if it helps.